# Blank white Screen in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Anybody can help me? I'm getting a blank screen in laravel. I don't  know where is the problem ... I run these commands from different    sources.

```
chmod -R o+w app/storage/
chmod -R o+w storage/
chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache storage
composer dump-autoload
Composer update
php artisan key:generate
```

Heres my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please help me I'm stuck in it.

Comment: Enable error reporting from `php.ini`

Comment: Check your server error logs, as well as your Laravel logs in `storage/logs`

Comment: Did you change something in the `.htaccess`? How do you serve your files? `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Hi @WahyuKristianto nothing is showing in  error .There is no error it is working fine on localhost when I do ```php artisan serve```.

Comment: Hi @brombeer it is working fine on localhost but not on the server. No I do not change anything on ```.htaccess```

Comment: And what webserver is "the server" using? Apache? Does it have `mod_rewrite` enabled? nginx?

Comment: @brombeer I'm using shared-hosting i don't know is they are using **Nginx or Apache**

Comment: Time to find out, maybe ask their support. See if mod_rewrite is enabled (if using Apache). nginx doesn't have support for `.htaccess` out of the box iirc

Comment: Hi, @brombeer Thanks for your help. I ask to support they are using **Apache**

Comment: Then you also need to find out if reading `.htaccess` files and `mod_rewrite` is enabled in Apache. If you can access the webserver log files you might also find useful information in the server's access/error logs.

Comment: okay @brombeer I'll ask to support.